# Setting a variable via dropdownlist in order to limit an index view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller, drop-down-menu

I have a Products controller, and each product includes a location attribute.
I want the 'Home Page', so the 'Home' controller view, to display a dropdownlist of the different locations for the products. Once a location is selected, I need the index view for my products controller to show ONLY products from that location. I have it set up as follows:

**'Home Index View'**

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
@model ListView.Controllers.AspNetProduct

...

@using (Html.BeginForm("IndexLocation", "Products", FormMethod.Get))
    {
        <p>
            Enter your location: <br />
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Location, ListView.Controllers.ProductsController.Locations)
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </p>
    }
```

**Locations. List located in ProductsController**

```
// Location List
    public static List<SelectListItem> Locations = new List<SelectListItem>()
    {
        new SelectListItem() {Text="Beaverton-Hillsboro, OR", Value="Beaverton-Hillsboro, OR"},
        new SelectListItem() {Text="Corvallis, OR", Value="Corvallis, OR"},
        new SelectListItem() {Text="Eugene, OR", Value="Eugene, OR"},
        new SelectListItem() {Text="Medford, OR", Value="Medford, OR"},
        new SelectListItem() {Text="Portland, OR", Value="Portland, OR"},
        new SelectListItem() {Text="Salem, OR", Value="Salem, OR"},
        new SelectListItem() {Text="Tualatin, OR", Value="Tualatin, OR"},
        new SelectListItem() {Text="Vancouver, WA", Value="Vancouver, WA"},
        new SelectListItem() {Text="Wilsonville, OR", Value="Wilsonville, OR"}
    };
```

**'ProductsController Index & IndexLocation Method'**

```
public ActionResult IndexLocation(string location)
    {
        ViewBag.location = location;

        return View("Index");
    }

    // GET: Products
    public ActionResult Index(string category, string searchString)
    {
        string location = ViewBag.location;

        var CategoryLst = new List<string>();

        var CategoryQry = from d in db.AspNetProducts
                          orderby d.Category
                          select d.Category;

        CategoryLst.AddRange(CategoryQry.Distinct());
        ViewBag.category = new SelectList(CategoryLst);

        var aspNetProducts = db.AspNetProducts.Include(a => a.AspNetUser);

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(location))
        {
            aspNetProducts = aspNetProducts.Where(a => a.Location == location);
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            aspNetProducts = aspNetProducts.Where(a => a.Title.Contains(searchString));
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(category))
        {
            aspNetProducts = aspNetProducts.Where(a => a.Category == category);
        }

        return View(aspNetProducts.ToList());
    }
```

My home page show's the dropdownmenu with the appropriate options, but when I select a location and press enter, it tries redirecting to the Products View, but I get an error with the category lookup for my products index: 
"*There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'category'.*"

This is how the start of my Products View Index looks, and it works great for searching if I start the build at this page, but it's not working if I start from the homepage, select the location, THEN redirect to this view..

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Products", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <p>
        Category: @Html.DropDownList("category", "All")
        Title: @Html.TextBox("SearchString")
        <input type="submit" value="Search" /><br />
        @Html.ActionLink("Clear Filters", "Index", "Products")
    </p>
} <br />
```

**Any help is appreciated, because I'm stuck..!**

Comment: Have you tried debugging, and if so exactly where does it throw an error?

Comment: You have a number of issues, the primary one causing the error if that in the `IndexLocation()` location method, you return the Index View, but do not pass a model to it. It's not clear exactly why your taking this approach, but you need to redirect to the `Index()` method or assign the `ViewBag.category` property in the `IndexLocation` method so you pass `category` to the view (currently its `null` hence the exception)

Comment: @StephenMuecke
It ends up throwing the error at:

    `Category: @Html.DropDownList("category", "All")`

I will attempt redirecting to the index method instead. Do you have different/better solution for what I'm trying to do?

Comment: The error is because `category` is null (you never pass a value for `category` to the view in the `IndexLocation()` method, only in the `Index()` method (when you do `ViewBag.category = new SelectList(CategoryLst);`). You really should consider using ajax for this to avoid all the redirects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line below of your code looks for a ViewBag.category :

```
Category: @Html.DropDownList("category", "All")
```

That means to make sure that all your controllers must asign to a ViewBag.category a select list, the same way you did to ViewBag.locations, otherwise you will have the "There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'category'."

And another suggestion it's to use Ajax.BeginForm to reload partials views on your master page, without needing to redirect

Comment: Any help or tutorial links for using Ajax.BeginForm? No really familiar with how to do this

Comment: This post I wrote in portuguese, so use your browser to translate to english, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/53624/22542 , and what more can I do for you voting for my answer to your post or check as favorite ?